# Dog bites at people's feet when they get close

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression

I have a 3 year old Yorkie.  He recently picked up a new mannerism that is causing some problems.  He will growl and bite at peoples shoes when they step close to him.

A few thing's I've noticed about the behavior:

- It's never me or my wife that he bites at
- It's often when he's under a table or chair (so maybe it surprises him or he doesn't see the persons face), but not always.
- It's when the feet get close, but not necessarily close enough to step on him.  He will attack the feet from his position
- Usually men (maybe the bigger feet)
- Usually leather shoes (this could just be a coincidence)

The items I say "usually" with are because I originally thought that each occurrence was related to that, but he proved me wrong by attacking a woman's foot once and recently some Velcro shoes (yes, I said Velcro, can't say I blamed him for that one).

Anyway, most people have thought it was funny, but he's not playing around.  He's seriously violent when he gets into that mode and since he's so small he's easy to get under control, but sometimes I'll be talking to someone and not necessarily watching him. As soon as I look down I'll notice he's on the end of his leash biting a person with the intention of killing their foot.

I do fear that maybe he would do it to someone who is bare footed, or maybe even a child someday (but I think it does relate to the bigger feet).

Does anyone know why this would have recently started happening?  He's small but I don't think he's ever really been stepped on (could be wrong I guess).  And does anyone know what I might do to curb this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: What actual commands does your dog respond to, what is he trained to do? You should be able to curb this with a 'Leave' command, or a sit and stay with a reward when he leaves the person alone. Also has he actually been stepped on at all prior to this behaviour occurring? Perhaps he was by accident (that you don't know of) and now it's a fear response?

Comment: "...sometimes I'll be talking to someone and not necessarily watching him..." I don't mean to criticize, but if your dog does this, you should always be aware of his whereabouts around people. If he has never been to obedience school, that is a good start. You can't let this go on; at worse, it might result in an infected bite and some expensive bills for you to pay.

Comment: This just started happening to my 3 year old Yorkie too. Out of the blue. He used to be very well behaved and has been to training school etc. My situation is exactly the same and has happened even more so in my parents house when we visit for a week or two straight. I can't figure it out either but am open to hearing what you did about this.

Comment: @Stephanie, honestly I haven't done much. He still does it. I've gotten better at holding him closer to me on the leash when I talk to people on a walk, I might put him outside or hold him if someone comes over (depending on if he decides to try to bite them). Same triggers as I noticed way back 4 years ago: usually bigger feet, usually leather shoes, etc.  Never seen him do it to bare feet.  It's more of a nuisance, he's never hurt anyone, but he wants to!